# Error:(246, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''

Tags: android, gradle

When I upgraded android studio to version 3 I've got this problem:

```
Error:(246, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''.
```

this is my gradle:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.faravani.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

please help me i don't know what should I do.

Comment: did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

change

```
supportLibraryVersion = "25.4.0"
```

to

```
supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.1"
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename rippleColor attribute in your attr file (I presume attrs.xml). It is probably in conflict with some android theme attribute .